# How do I create backward compatibility for Power Queries in Excel 2016 that were developed in Excel 2021?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logic, powerquery

[image]

I have been working on project and stuck at Error which reflects,

> [Expression.Error] 5 arguments were passed to function which expects between 2 and 4.

I have made a project in Excel 2021 Student and home version, then I have needed the same file in my another equipment which has Excel 2016 since its a work laptop. Now some of the Power queries are not working in Excel 2016 version. Is there anything I can do it in a code to make it work out in older version?

[image]

Error image has Green table of Vendor and Index which looks the code.

I have tried to make edits in the code but nothing seems to be working. Below is the code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tb_Vendor_1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Vendor", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Repeat({""},#"Para-VendorQty")),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Vendor] = "Vendor")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Vendor"}),
    #"Expanded Custom1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Custom1",{{"Custom", "Vendor"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Vendor Name", each ""),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Vendor Details", each ""),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "Vendor", "Vendor Name", "Vendor Details"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

Comment: Remove the `Int64.Type` argument from your `Table.AddIndexColumn` function.